# Reading video stream and writing it to a buffer

Tags: c++, directshow

I'm writing a program in C++ using DirectShow API in order to accelerate video encoding part. This program should read video stream from Video Capture Card, and pass it to the encoder, without intermediate raw data file which is usually passed.

But encoder is not my software, in fact, it was bought. 
This encoder used to accept a raw data file with it's details and give an encoded file as an output. So I've decided to read video stream from Video Capture Card, save it to some buffer, and when the size of a buffer is appropriate (appropriate is specified in encoder) pass it to encoder.

But I'm new to DirectShow as well as to a whole multimedia programming, so what I'm asking is an advise about a function to use to read a stream, or about total solution, or any useful links.

Thanks in Advance

EDIT 1: What I meant by Accelerate is to read video stream in encoder directly, instead of creating intermediate YUV file and making encoder to read YUV file.

Comment: A file input-only codec?  This doesn't sound like any acceleration is going to happen for live streaming.

Comment: I must have written it wrong, english is not my native language, sorry. I meant acceleration of total architecture, since writing 7GB of data to a file and then reading it is not as effective as passing data directly to an encoder

Comment: The biggest challenge might be matching the raw input to the encoder, 7GB is going to be a only a few seconds.

Comment: @Steve true, basically that's what I'm looking for, any suggestions?

Comment: If you purchased the encoder I would assume you have some details on its preferred input.

Comment: @Steve yes I do have preferred input, but all of these inputs are files, different types of them, but none of them is about stream, so I've decided change it within the encoder, so what I'm looking for is possibility to capture portions of stream provided by Video Capture Card